# Why are some new questions protected?

Tags: support

I just asked a couple of questions and noticed that [one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71359/can-i-estimate-remaining-battery-life-by-measuring-its-voltage-with-the-same-mcu) was protected but [another](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71374/is-there-a-minimum-output-current-for-voltage-regulators) wasn't, although both had received good answers. Some other new questions have also been protected. How come?

I don't think *"thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users* would be a problem for these questions.

Comment: @w5vo Thanks, but I read that question before asking when I searched for "protected". Neither of the two questions seems to answer my question. They don't even mention protecting questions.

Comment: I've read it several times now and it seems to be about some problem user who will be suspended for years. Is the answer that questions are protected so that this single user won't be able to answer?

Comment: Anna, That is what it all boils down to. On your protected question, that user had posted an answer. I "protected" it to prevent that user from spamming your question.

Comment: Ok, then I understand.